# Set up Permanent Flutter Path for 2022 MacBook M1 Pro

Tags: flutter, macos, path

I am trying to install Flutter on my M1 Pro. I am following along with this setup process -> https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path
So far, I've downloaded Xcode & the Flutter SDK for Apple Silicon devices.

If I use the command, export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin", which is a temporary path, it works. It's making the path permanent that I can't get to work. I didn't have a hidden file named .zshrc so I had to create one via the default EditText app. Currently, I have a .zshrc file with no extension in my home directory.
Per the Flutter instructions, I'm supposed to add this line in the .zshrc file -> export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_OF_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/bin". It currently looks like -> export PATH="$PATH:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Development/flutter/bin".

I'm supposed to be able to close out of everything and then open a new terminal and type "flutter" and it work.. Instead I get, "zsh: command not found: flutter".

Can someone explain what I'm missing? According to an Academind tutorial, this should work.

Comment: If you use the command `cat ~/.zshrc | egrep "^\s*export"` can you see your flutter path?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by deleting my .zshrc file and creating a .zshenv file. In the terminal I typed vim ~/.zshenv

Started a new terminal and flutter works!